# Advanced Calculator Kata

Tags: ruby, calculator, math-expression-eval, rspec

This is the `CalculatorAdvanced` Kata from the Kata gem. I've just finished it and would love some feedback on my solution.

> ```
> CalculatorAdvanced Kata
>    Add Method
>       Allow the expression to handle new lines between numbers
>          - example: "1\n2\n3" computes to 6
>          - example: "2,3\n4" computes to 9
>          - detail: Consecutive use of delimeters should raise an exception
>          - example: "1,\n2" or "1\n,2"
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>       Calling method with a negative number will give an exception
>          - detail: The exception should tell the user "negatives not allowed"
>          - detail: The exception will list the negative number that was in the string
>          - detail: The exception should list all negatives if there is more than one
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>    Diff and Product Method
>       should raise the same exceptions as the add method
>          - detail: Consecutive Delimiters
>          - detail: Negative Numbers
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>    Define Custom Delimeters
>       Allow the add method to accept a different delimiter
>          - detail: The line of the string will contain "//[delimeter]\n...
>          - detail: This line is optional and all previous tests should pass
>          - example: "//[;]\n1;2" computes to 3
>          - detail: "1;2" should raise an exception
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>       Allow the diff method to accept a different delimiter like add
>          - example: //[;]\n2;1 computes to 1
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>       Allow the prod method to accept a different delimiter like add
>          - example: //[;]\n2;1 computes to 2
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>       Allow the div method to accept a different delimiter like add
>          - example: //[;]\n3;2 computes to 1
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>       Allow the add method to handle multiple different delimeters
>          - example: multiple delimeters can be specified using "//[delimeter]...[delimeter]\n...
>          - example: "//[*][;]\n1*2;3" computes to 6
>          - example: "//[*][;][#]\n5*4;3#2" computes to -4
>          - example: "//[#][;][*]\n1*2#3;4,5\n6" computes to 21
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>       Allow the diff method to handle multiple different delimeters
>          - example: "//[*][;]\n1*2;3" computes to -4
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>       Allow the prod method to handle multiple different delimeters
>          - example: "//[*][;]\n1*2;3" computes to 6
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
>       Allow the div method to handle multiple different delimeters
>          - example: "//[*][;]\n1*2;3" computes to 0
>
> completed (Y|n):
>
> ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┓
> ┃ Requirement                                                                      ┃ Time     ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Allow the expression to handle new lines between numbers                         ┃ 00:37:20 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Calling method with a negative number will give an exception                     ┃ 00:20:55 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ should raise the same exceptions as the add method                               ┃ 00:08:41 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Allow the add method to accept a different delimiter                             ┃ 00:22:51 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Allow the diff method to accept a different delimiter like add                   ┃ 00:06:04 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Allow the prod method to accept a different delimiter like add                   ┃ 00:01:49 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Allow the div method to accept a different delimiter like add                    ┃ 00:01:46 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Allow the add method to handle multiple different delimeters                     ┃ 00:55:48 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Allow the diff method to handle multiple different delimeters                    ┃ 00:00:54 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Allow the prod method to handle multiple different delimeters                    ┃ 00:00:38 ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╊━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ Allow the div method to handle multiple different delimeters                     ┃ 00:00:43 ┃
> ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━┛
> ```

And, here's the Class I created:

```ruby
class Calculatoradvanced
  attr_reader :expr

  def expr=(expression='')
    @expr = expression
    validate_expression
  end

  alias_method :initialize, :expr=

  def add
    @values.inject(&:+)
  end

  def diff
    @values.inject(&:-)
  end

  def prod
    @values.inject(&:*)
  end

  def div
    @values.inject(&:/)
  end

  private

  def validate_expression
    if @expr =~ /,\n/ || @expr =~ /\n,/
      raise "Consecutive Delimiters"
    end

    split_string = ",\n"

    if match = @expr.match(/\/\/([^\n]*)\n(.*)/m)
      delimeters, @expr = match.captures
      delimeters = delimeters.split(/[\[\]]/)
      delimeters.reject! { |delimeter| delimeter == '' }
      split_string = "#{Regexp.escape(delimeters.join)}" + split_string
    end

    @values = @expr.split(/[#{split_string}]/).map(&:to_i)

    @negatives = @values.select { |value| value < 0 }
    if (@negatives && @negatives.any?)
      raise "negatives not allowed: #{@negatives.join(', ')}"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm really unsatisfied with the test for Consecutive Delimiters. If anyone knows of a good way to make that test more flexible, I'd love to hear it.

Here are my specs:

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'
require 'calculatoradvanced'

describe Calculatoradvanced do
  subject(:calc) { Calculatoradvanced.new(expression) }
  context 'with an empty expression' do
    let(:expression) { '' }
    specify { expect { calc }.to_not raise_exception }
  end
  context 'with expression "1\n2\n3"' do
    let(:expression) { "1\n2\n3" }

    specify { expect { calc }.to_not raise_exception }
    its(:add) { should eq(6) }
  end
  context 'with expression "2,3\n4"' do
    let(:expression) { "2,3\n4" }

    its(:add) { should eq(9) }
    its(:expr) { should eq("2,3\n4") }
  end
  context 'with expression "1,\n2"' do
    let(:expression) { "1,\n2" }

    specify { expect { calc.add }.to raise_exception }
  end
  context 'with expression "1\n,2"' do
    let(:expression) { "1\n,2" }

    specify { expect { calc.add }.to raise_exception }
  end
  shared_examples_for 'expression validation' do
    specify { expect { method }.to raise_exception(RuntimeError, /negatives not allowed/) }
    specify { expect { method }.to raise_exception(RuntimeError, /-1, -2, -3/) }
  end
  context 'with expression "-1,-2\n-3"' do
    let(:expression) { "-1,-2\n-3" }
    context '.add' do
      let(:method) { calc.add }

      it_behaves_like 'expression validation'
    end
    context '.diff' do
      let(:method) { calc.diff }
      it_behaves_like 'expression validation'
    end
    context '.prod' do
      let(:method) { calc.prod }
      it_behaves_like 'expression validation'
    end
  end
  context 'with expression "//[;]\n1;2"' do
    let(:expression) { "//[;]\n1;2" }

    its(:add) { should eq(3) }
  end
  context 'with expression "//[;]\n2;1"' do
    let(:expression) { "//[;]\n2;1" }
    its(:diff) { should eq(1) }
    its(:prod) { should eq(2) }
  end
  context 'with expression "//[;]\n3;2"' do
    let(:expression) { "//[;]\n3;2" }

    its(:div) { should eq(1) }
  end
  context 'with expression "//[*][;]\n1*2;3"' do
    let(:expression) { "//[*][;]\n1*2;3" }
    its(:add)  { should eq(6)  }
    its(:diff) { should eq(-4) }
    its(:prod) { should eq(6)  }
    its(:div)  { should eq(0)  }
  end
  context 'with expression "//[*][;][#]\n5*4;3#2"' do
    let(:expression) { "//[*][;][#]\n5*4;3#2" }
    its(:diff) { should eq(-4) }
  end
  context 'with expression "//[#][;][*]\n1*2#3;4,5\n6"' do
    let(:expression) { "//[#][;][*]\n1*2#3;4,5\n6" }
    its(:add) { should eq(21) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to re-write your code but give some pointers instead, I hope it's helpful:

- Those four methods (`add`, ...) do basically the same thing, why don't you abstract them?
- `inject` accepts a symbol: `@values.inject(:+)`
- split_string -> maybe this? `string.split(/[,$]/)`
- Variable `delimeters` has three different values on the course of the method! Different values deserve different names.
- `if @negatives`: That's an unnecessary check, `@negatives` is an array, so it will never be falsy (in Ruby: `nil`/`false`).
- `@negatives.any?` If you are going to perform an `any?` operation, do it directly (with a block), don't do a `select` + `any?`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'll try using the old `method_not_found` trick and then having a case statement for `add`, etc... I'm a bit prejudice against that pattern but ... this is just for fun so why not make sure I understand that pattern before rejecting it. Good catch on `inject()`. Re: `split_string`, it actually does need to be "\n" and not "$". The newline character can occur multiple times in the string. `delimiters` is also an interesting case. I only want to final value so I'm stripping away unwanted characters in each line. I could try chaining the whole thing together ...

Comment: -- continued :) -- Re: @negatives, the reason I'm checking `@negatives && @negatives.any?` is that, if there are no negative numbers, `@negatives` will be nil. This will cause `@negatives.any?` to throw an error because `any?` isn't defined on the Nil class. Also, I'm using select to get an array of all negatives because I need to print all negative numbers in the exception. I hope that clarifies what I was thinking with the choices I've made. Please let me know if I'm missing something and there's a better way to satisfy the requirements. Thanks!

Comment: Re: Re: @negatives, you're right! `select` will return the empty array if it doesn't find anything so `@negatives.any?` is the only test that's needed there :)

Comment: please don't use `method_not_found`!

Comment: lulz ... I know, I felt dirty doing it ;) What would you suggest to get the same effect (i.e. a case statement that maps the method to a symbol to pass to `inject`)?

Comment: You can use `define_method`, but I am not also a big fan of it. On second thought, it's 4 methods, i guess it's no big deal to have separate code...